# Extracting information from an HTML table using node.js and Selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to parse data from an HTML table using node.js and Selenium. There is a condition depending on which column of the table I am looking at however and I can't seem to get my code to work. Currently I have

```
var webdriver          = require('selenium-webdriver');
var By                 = webdriver.By;
var driver             = *webdriver instance*;
var table_row_xpath    = *xpath of all table rows*
var table_header_xpath = *xpath table header elements*

driver.findElements(By.xpath(table_row_xpath)).then(function(rows) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].findElements(By.xpath('td')).then(function(cells) {
            for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                headers[j].getText().then(function(header_text) {
                    if (header_text != '') {
                        cells[j].getText().then(function(cell_text) {
                            console.log(header_text, cell_text);
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('No header');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

It seems however that having the `cells[j].getText().then` within the `headers[j].getText().then` is causing the script to fail.    If I wrote this instead as

```
******** Inner Loop *********
headers[j].getText().then(function(header_text) {
    console.log(header_text);
})

cells[j].getText().then(function(cell_text) {
    console.log(cell_text);
});
```

Then the values are printed out in the correct order but obviously in this case I cannot perform my check as to whether the header is an empty string.

How can I correct this? Also bonus points if you can show me how to make the code more readable, I'm very new to node.js!